# Very slow SSH connection Pycharm

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, interpreter

I've been trying for days to get this to work, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I'm developing on a remote server on another continent which therefore has a high ping (around 300 ms). Every time I start run / debug or a new console Pycharm establishes a new SSH connection and this takes a very long time (on average about 30 seconds). I do this over 100 times a day so it's quite a productivity killer :(

My question therefore is: how to speed up the SSH connection?

As for what I've tried so far:

- SSH compression
- Only IPv4
- It seems using SSH multiplexing is the way to go. This way Pycharm doesn't have to establish a whole new SSH connection every time it connects to the server. When the remote interpreter is running a command takes only a second or two. Unfortunately because Pycharm uses it's own SSH library (Java Jsch I think) I just cannot create a /ssh/ssh_config with the ControlMaster directive.
- It also looks like pycharm tries to confirm that the version of the pycharm_helpers is the same as the local. I think an extra SSH connection is established for this, but have no idea how to disable this check.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm works in the same session which is used for running, debugging and uploading. It doesn't open a new session for each run or debug. So multiplexing is already in place.

Unfortunately, there is no way to disable pycharm_helpers version check, but it should not be an issue since, like I said, it uses the same session and it doesn't take much time to check one line of build.txt file.